# Could not find a declaration file for module '@microsoft/sp-application-base'

Tags: list, spfx, error, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I am building a application customizer extension to hide the Approve/Reject buttons in modern SharePoint page using instructions here: [Hiding Approve/Reject button in SharePoint modern experience views using SharePoint Framework](https://blog.cosmer.com/hiding-approve-reject-button-in-sharepoint-modern-experience-views/).

And following Microsoft Learn here: [Use page placeholders from Application Customizer (Hello World part 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

At the start of my code I am getting an error on importing components from sp-application-base:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> '@microsoft/sp-application-base'.
> 'c:/EG/HideApprovalControls/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-application-base/lib-commonjs/index.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/microsoft__sp-application-base` if it exists or add a new
> declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@microsoft/sp-application-base';`ts(7016)

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer,
  PlaceholderName,
  PlaceholderContent
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';

import * as strings from 'HideApprovalControlsApplicationCustomizerStrings';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'HideApprovalControlsApplicationCustomizer';
```

my dependencies are:

```
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-application-base": "^1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.18.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
```